# Actionscript-3: Button within movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, function, variables, button

So, I have a movieclip called bg with a button named sleep_btn within it. I am doing the coding on a layer on the stage, and it went like this:

```
sleep_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sleepClick);
function sleepClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    health = 100;
    day += 1;
}
```

I quickly realized that it would not work without the movieclip being defined as well in the coding, so I tried:

```
bg.sleep_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sleepClick);
function sleepClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    health = 100;
    day = day + 1;
}
```

My error was gone, but I found that when I clicked on the button, the health and day stayed the same.

The day is in a text field, with coding like this:

```
var day:int = 1;
if (day==1) date.text = "July 1";
if (day==2) date.text = "July 2";
if (day==3) date.text = "July 3";
```

and on and on

And the health is a 101 frame movieclip with coding like:

```
var health:int = 100;
   lifebar.gotoAndStop(health + 1);
```

***EDIT***

**Top Banner Layer:**

```
stop();
var health:int = 100;
   lifebar.gotoAndStop(health + 1);
    //Can write this also: lifebar.health += 45;
    trace("health is "+health);
    trace("day is "+day);

var day:int = 1;
updateDay();

function updateDay():void{
if (day==1) date.text = "July 1";
if (day==2) date.text = "July 2";
if (day==3) date.text = "July 3";
if (day==4) date.text = "July 3";
}

fortyfivedown_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fortyfivedownClick);
function fortyfivedownClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    if (health < 45) {
       return;
    }
    health -= 45;
    if(health < 0) health = 0;
    else if(health > 100) health = 100;
    lifebar.gotoAndStop(health + 1);
     trace("health is "+health);
}

bg.sleep_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sleepClick);
function sleepClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    health = 100;
    day = day + 1;

    //update lifebar
    lifebar.gotoAndStop(health + 1);

    //update day
    updateDay();
}
```

Comment: Hi Triple, did you try to switch over to using the class instead of having the code on the timeline?

Comment: Hey, I tried, but I messed up my project, and kept the layer coding. I'm not very good at actionscript 3.

Comment: Yeah I know you're just getting started, honestly using Flash IDE is pretty difficult I usually code with Flex, but the Flash IDE does have it's good points with the WYSIWYG type editing and whatnot.  Keeping things in the timeline is going to make it more complicated to know when things are in scope.  Get the link to mediafire I posted on the last post it has the fla and as file they just need to be in the same folder, then if you right click on HealthBar in the library and go to edit class you can modify the as file.

Comment: I should be more specific by Flex I meant I use Flex/FlashBuilder instead of the Flash IDE because coding in there is much nicer.  Either way using classes for your movie clips to keep track of properties you want to associate with them or you want to affect them will be easier.

Comment: ALright, I'll try again, thanks

Comment: Alright, I 've changed so many of my variables and coding, I put it above. If I am going to use the package, class method, are ALL of my variables declared on that actionscript file?

Comment: Why is your code spread out onto different layers?

Comment: I've been learning as I go, and I guess I thought it would help me learn better. I'll put my coding all on one layer though, if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't updating the actual UI textboxes with the new data. Move your day determining code (which could be massively cleaned up, but that is out of the scope of this question) into its own function so it can be reused:

```
var day:int = 1;
updateDay();

function updateDay():void{
    if (day==1) date.text = "July 1";
    if (day==2) date.text = "July 2";
    if (day==3) date.text = "July 3";
    // ...and so on...
}
```

Then call that function (and the health update) in the `sleepClick` handler:

```
function sleepClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    health = 100;
    day = day + 1;

    //update lifebar
    lifebar.gotoAndStop(health + 1);

    //update day
    updateDay();
}
```

Comment: Hello there, thank-you for your help. I tried the coding, but I found that I click on another button, which decreases the health by 45, when I click on the sleep button, the day stays the same while the health goes up. Also, I traced the day and the health, and the day is 0 when it should be 1, and the health 100, which is what it should be. Do you have any idea what is wrong with the day variable?

Answer (score 0):

Is `health` and `day` displayed on the stage? What type are they? Are you setting the text of a TextField to their values?

If they are just variables and they are not displayed by a UI you won't see them change.

Comment: I am very new to action script, can you please explain what you mean by that?